# How to show jpg image in case if google swiffy html5 content is not supported by browser

Tags: html, flash

I have converted a flash animation using google swiffy. But how can a show a GIF image in case if browser does not supports google swiffy converted flash content ?

Answer (score 0):

google swiffy uses html5 canvas, you can check if the html5 canvas is supported or not. Put the image in div so you can hide/unhide base on the checking. 
I had a similar implementation in my project and this is how I do it.

```js
                var test_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");                      
          var canvascheck = (test_canvas.getContext) ? true : false ;                     
          if (canvascheck)
             //show the swiffy here and hide the image div                       
          else
            //show the image div
```